# How to change a field value on selection in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a Tableau viz which looks like this:

[image]

It is required to change the value of a "Checked" column of a particular record to "Yes" by clicking on it.
Can this be achieved in Tableau? What are the options that I can use in Tableau to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Tableau only connects to data, it does not write back to the data source and update values.

Comment: Here are a few workarounds suggested by Tableau community for this problem:

https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D74T000000tNh1/how-to-change-a-field-value-on-selection-in-tableau?s1oid=00D4T000000Dj8G&s1nid=0DB4T000000GnPK&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0054T000001uMOC&emtm=1597970422279&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0&t=1598225035740